# expr string matching

Tags: regex, bash

I want to match one or more occurance for ex. of blah using expr.

This works.

```
$ expr "blahblahblah" : 'blahblah'
8
```

What is wrong with this regular expression?

```
$ expr "blahblahblah" : '\(blah\)\+'
blah
```

I want the number of characters matched.

Comment: Why is "using expr" a part of the question, rather than "regex-matching a string and knowing how many characters matched"?

Comment: expr is an external command, not a part of bash -- if you _really_ want an expr command to do this, it isn't a bash question at all.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is tagged `bash`, there are better facilities than expr in modern versions of the shell, which do exactly what you want:

```
$ re='(blah)+'
$ [[ foo_blahblah_bar =~ $re ]] && echo "${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
8
```

Comment: Yes, I am using it in a bash script, so bash only syntax definetely makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need `\(\)` instead of `()` and `\+` instead of `+`.
But that is not all.

You can't use groups `()` and get the length of matched string simultaneously.

Pattern matches return the string matched between ( and ) or null; if ( and ) are not used, they return the number of characters matched or 0.

You must use `wc` to get the length of the string:

```
$ expr "blahblahblahblah" : '\(\(blah\)\+\)' | wc -c
17
```

Or using parameters expansion:

```
$ m=$(expr "blahblahblahblah" : '\(\(blah\)\+\)') 
$ echo ${#m}
16
```

(wc -c counts the end of line also, hence the difference).

But if you can write the regular expression without groups, you get the length:

```
$ expr "blahhhhhbl" : "blah\+"
8
```

Comment: No reason to use wc -- you can get the length with parameter expansion, which avoids the overhead of forking off a subprocess, setting up a pipeline, capturing its output, etc.

Comment: ...well, I said that before running `type expr`; turns out it's an external command, so there's fork+wait+read overhead in running it no matter what.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: anyway ${#a} looks better than `wc -c`. And your answer (`[[ =~ ]]`) is even better

Comment: Guys thanks, I am impressed! I resort to bash only in seldom need situations, but I am going to be coming back here more often in future.

Comment: bash is a really mighty thing. I think, you will be excited

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
echo "blahblahblah" | sed -n 's!\(\(blah\)*\).*!\1!p' | wc -c
```